# How to find all items not related to another model - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a fairly complicated lookup i'm trying to do in Rails and I'm not entirely sure how hoping someone can help.

I have two models, User and Place.

A user is related to Place twice. Once for visited_places and once for planned_places. Its a many to many relationship but using has_many :through. Here's the relationship from User.

```
has_many :visited_places
has_many :visited, :class_name=>"Place", :through=>:visited_places, :source=>:place

has_many :planned_places
has_many :planned, :class_name=>"Place", :through=>:planned_places, :source=>:place
```

In place the relationship is also defined. Here's the definition there

```
has_many :visited_users, :class_name=>"User", :through=>:visited_places  
has_many :planned_users, :class_name=>"User", :through=>:planned_places
```

I'm trying to write a find on Place that returns all places in the database that aren't related to a User through either visited or planned. Right now I'm accomplishing this by simply querying all Places and then subtracting visited and planned from the results but I want to add in pagination and I'm worried this could complicate that. Here's my current code.

```
all_places = Place.find(:all)        
all_places = all_places - user.visited - user.planned
```

Anyone know how i can accomplish this in just a call to Place.find. Also this is a Rails 3 app so if any of the active record improvements make this easier they are an option.

Comment: OT, but you may want to rename your join model -- Seems like your :visited_places join model should be renamed to "PlaceVisits", and then you can have `has_many :place_visits` and `has_many :visited_places, :through=>:place_visits`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
unvisited_places = Place.find(:all, :conditions => "id NOT IN(#{visited_places.map(&:place_id)})")
```

That's the general idea -- it can be made more efficient and convenient depending on your final needs.

Comment: Generally this would work, but to create the list of id's, using `visited_places.map` as you wrote, rails has to query all visited_places first. It would be better to do that in 1 query, in 1 go. Let the database do that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show it but if I am right in assuming that the `VisitedPlace` and `PlannedPlace` models have a `belongs_to :user` relationships then those tables have a `user_id` secondary key, right?

So in that case I would think it would be most efficient to do this in the database in which case you are looking for a select across a table join of `places`, `visited_places` and `planned_places` where `users.id` is not in either of `visited_places` or `planned_places`

Answer (score 0):

in sql:

```
select * from places where id not in 
  (
    (select place_id from visited_places where user_id = ?) 
  union 
    (select place_id from planned_places where user_id=?)
  )
```

If that query works, you can use as follows:

```
Places.find_by_sql(...the complete sql query ...)
```

I would not know how to write such a query, with an exclusion, in Rails 3 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar desire recently... I wanted to get all Model1s that weren't associated with a Model2. Using Rails 4.1, here's what I did:

```
Model1.where.not(id: Model2.select(:user_id).uniq)
```

This creates a nested SELECT, like @nathanvda suggested, effectively letting the database do all the work. Example SQL produced is:

```
SELECT "model1s".* FROM "model1s"  WHERE ("model1s"."id" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT "model2s"."model1_id" FROM "model2s"))
```