# How do you set up this association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I want a "group" to have many members. I already have a user and a profile model, and if a user identifies itself as a "group", I want it to be able to list its members. Therefore, I'm thinking of letting a profile `has_many :members, :class_name => 'User'` so that a "group" can select existing users. However, I also want to let a group list members that are not existing users. How would I set up this association? Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: so a Profile has_many members (User) ? and User belongs_to Profile?

Comment: yep, except profile belongs_to user

Comment: It would be helpful to see your models. Wanna show us your existing associations in each model?

Answer (score 0):

"let a group list members that are not existing users" -- do you mean "let a group list **users** that are not existing **members**"?

If so, then this answer I gave a while back might help: [How to find all items not related to another model - Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240827/how-to-find-all-items-not-related-to-another-model-rails-3/3240976#3240976)

Comment: not really, what I mean is that I want to let a group (a.k.a profile) have many users, but I want them to either be existing users in the database or for them to choose new users that are not in the database by specifying a name that would be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this lambda in your User model:

```
named_scope :not_members, lambda { |profile_id| where("id NOT IN (?)", 
                                   User.where( :profile_id => profile_id ).map(&:id) ) }
```

later in your code:

```
@not_members = User.not_members(some_profile_id)
```

PS: This is not tested